# The mathematical frog and his adventure

Tags: probability

Let's say that there is a mathematical frog. This mathematical frog lies on a mathematical lily pad number 0, with lily pads extending infinitely in either direction. The lily pads to the left of 0 are negative, and the lily pads to the right of 0 are positive. In a move, the frog can either go left, go right, or stay with equal probability. I want to find the probability that the frog goes to pad 7 within 10 moves.

How would you solve this? I am thinking recursion (maybe), but I don't know how to set it up. Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Exactly $10$ or $\le 10$?

Comment: Sorry... within 10

Comment: Well, I presume you mean $\le 10 $ moves then...

Comment: Politically correct version of the drunkard's walk...

Answer (score 3):

I would just make a spreadsheet with columns for the lily pads and rows for the probability of each position after jumps.  Each cell should be the average of the three above.  If you want a rational answer, each cell should have the number of routes to that pad after that many jumps so is the total of the three above.  Then divide by $3^{10}$

Comment: I like practical answers.

Answer (score 3):

Guide:

- If the frog doesn't stay at the same position, it can only reach pad number $7$ in $7$ moves (move right all the time) or $9$ moves (move left once, move right $8$ times). This can be derived using parity.
- If the frog stays at the same location once, it can reach pad number $7$ in $8$ moves or $10$ moves.
- If the frog stays at the same location twice, it can reach pad number $7$ in $9$ moves.
- If the frog stays at the same location for $3$ times, it can reach pad number $7$ in $10$ moves.

Comment: Notice also, that the last move must be a hop to the right.